# Finality of residual gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an algebraic stack, and $x \in |\mathcal{X}|$ a point such that the residual gerbe $\mathcal{G}_x$ of $\mathcal{X}$ at $x$ exists.  Let $\mathcal{Y}$ be a reduced algebraic stack, and $\mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$ a morphism such that the induced map on topological spaces factors through the inclusion $x \to |\mathcal{X}|$.  Does the map $\mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$ factor through $\mathcal{G}_x \to \mathcal{X}$? If not, are there any additional conditions one can place on $\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{X}$, or the map $\mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$ to get an affirmative answer?

I require $\mathcal{Y}$ to be reduced above as there are easy counterexamples to the above when $\mathcal{Y}$ is nonreduced (e.g. the identity map on the dual numbers).

Comment: Not always, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06MS. But see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0H25 for a positive result.

Comment: Great, thank you! Tag 0H25 looks like what I was looking for.